# SQL: Subselection from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm practising a bit on my SQL queries and I'm stuck here. I created a bunch of different tables and I want a table that retrieves different columns (redundantly at it sounds). The key here is the following: I want to select all the information related to the outputs' column from two different tables. The second table queried contains different attributes which corresponds to a third table's column.

To do that, I wrote this:

```
select   l.output_name,   
         l.output_date,   
         (select *
            from elt.attribute_key
           where attribute = ('a', 'b', 'c')   
         )
  from   etl.output l  
 where   l.version = 'local'  
   and   l.country = 'DE'
```

It gave me errors, and I think it's due to the nonexistent joining between tables, but I don't know where I should add. Furthermore, I would like to know I 'm tackling it properly.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Normally, one would use `JOIN` for this purpose.

Comment: Would you please give some sample data and what output you expect. At this stage your question is unclear. Also in your code there is a ( select ...) in field list. When you have that, you have to make sure it returns a scalar value, not a set of rows - and you cannot return multiple columns like that. Anyway your intent is unclear at this point to comment on more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if, you mean *CROSS JOIN*, So, Use :

```
select  l.output_name, l.output_date, 
        a.* 
  from  etl.output l  
  cross join elt.attribute_key a
  where l.version = 'local'  
    and l.country = 'DE'
    and a.attribute in ('a', 'b', 'c');
```